# Suppose that $n = 98!$. What is $100!$ in terms of $n$?

Tags: factorial

If $n = 98!$ then how do we find $100!$ in terms of $n$?

I am really stumped on this tricky question.

Comment: Hint: $99! = 99 \cdot 98 \cdot 97 \cdots 2 \cdot 1 = 99 \cdot 98!\,$.

Comment: What do you have to multiply $98!$ by in order to obtain $100!$?

Comment: $100!=100\cdot99\cdot98!=100\cdot99\cdot n=9900n$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Hint:**

$k!=\underbrace{1\cdot 2\cdot 3\cdots \cdot (k-1)\cdot k}_{k~\text{terms}}$

Now, noticing that $k!=(\underbrace{1\cdot 2\cdots (k-1)}_{(k-1)~\text{terms}})\cdot k = ((k-1)!)\cdot k$ you should be able to continue.